# If resp is a pointer to a response object, why don't we have to use resp* to access its value?

Tags: pointers, go, get, httprequest

I recently began studying Golang and the accompanying documentation. In the [Golang net/http documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Get) , the Get method is:

```
func Get(url string) (resp *Response, err error)
```

It is my understanding that this method returns a pointer to a response object or an error object (should an error occur). If `resp` is a pointer to a response object, why can the `resp`value be accessed using the following code:

```
func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://google.com")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

Should it not be `fmt.Println(*resp)` instead? There are many other examples like this throughout the documentation. I thought I understood pointers but I am obviously missing something. Any help in clarifying this would certainly be appreciated.

Comment: Rule of thumb: If you use fmt.Println to debug you must not try to infer the types from the printed output. fmt.Println does a lot of magic; which is fine but you either have to know that magic (read the documentation at least 10 times over 5 days) or use fmt.Printf which gives you control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If `resp` is a pointer to a response object, why can the [object itself] be accessed using [`fmt.Println(resp)`] ...  Should it not be `fmt.Println(*resp)` instead?

If you send to `fmt.Println` a pointer to an object, `fmt.Println` can use the pointer to reach the object itself (i.e., access it—and even modify it, but `fmt.Println` doesn't modify it).

If you send to `fmt.Println` a *copy* of the object, `fmt.Println` can use the copy of the object, i.e., access it (and cannot modify the original).

So in that sense, giving `fmt.Println` the pointer value is strictly more powerful than passing a copy of the object, because it can modify the object.  The `fmt` code does not *use* this power, but it's there in any other place that you might pass the pointer too.  But as long as `fmt.Println`:

1. notices that this is a pointer, and then
2. follows the pointer to access the underlying object,

then `fmt.Println` can *behave the same way* on both pointer-to-object and copy-of-object.

In fact, the `fmt.Print*` family of functions do not quite behave the same way with pointer-to-object and copy-of-object:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type T struct {
    Name string
    Value int
}

func main() {
    obj := T{Name: "bob", Value: 42}
    fmt.Println(&obj, obj)
    fmt.Printf("%#v %#v\n", &obj, obj)
}
```

When this is run ([try it on the Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/u4CDE_vpUuZ)), it prints:

```
&{bob 42} {bob 42}
&main.T{Name:"bob", Value:42} main.T{Name:"bob", Value:42}
```

That is, the default formatting, which you get with `%v` or `fmt.Println`, prints either:

```
{bob 42}
```

(copy of object) or:

```
&{bob 42}
```

(pointer to object).  The alternative format obtained with `%#v` adds the type, so that you either get:

```
main.T{Name:"bob", Value:42}
```

(copy of object) or:

```
&main.T{Name:"bob", Value:42}
```

What we see here is that `fmt.Println`, which takes an `interface{}` value, goes through the following process:

1. Inspect the type of the value.  Is it a pointer?  If so, remember that it was a pointer.  Print `<nil>` and do not go any further if it's a nil pointer; otherwise, obtain the object to which the pointer points.
2. Now that it's not a pointer:  What type does the value have?  If it's a `struct` type, print out its type name (`%#v`) or not (`%v`), prefixed with `&` if step 1 followed a pointer, and then the open brace and a list of the values of things inside the struct, and then a close brace to end the whole thing.

   When using `%#v`, print the names of the fields and print the values in a format suitable for use as Go source code.  Otherwise, just print the contents of strings and `int`s and so on.

Other pointer types do not always get the same treatment!  For instance, add a `int` variable, set it to some value, and call `fmt.Println(&i, i)`.  Note that this time you don't get `&42 42` or something like that, but rather `0x40e050 42` or something like that.  Try this with `fmt.Printf` and `%#v`.  So the output depends on the type and the formatting verb.

If you call functions that *must* modify their objects (such as the `scan` family in `fmt`), you *must* pass a pointer, since they need to have access to the objects to modify them.

Every function that can take values of unconstrained `interface{}` types (including everything in the `Print*` and `Scan*` family here) must document what they do with each actual type.  If they say, as the `Print*` family do, that when given a pointer to a struct type, they follow the pointer (if not nil), that lets you know that you can send the pointer instead of the object.

(Some functions in some libraries are guilty of under-documenting what they do, and you have to experiment.  This is not a great situation in general because the results of the experiment might be an accident of the current implementation, rather than a promised behavior that won't change in the future.  This is one reason to be chary of using `interface{}`: it means you have to write a lot of documentation.)